# MVVM: Set a getDrawable from a ViewModel

Tags: android, kotlin, mvvm

I'm moving all my app's logic from the fragment to the ViewModel and cannot move those methods that set drawables.
Example:

```
marker.icon = ContextCompat.getDrawable(requireContext(), R.drawable.waypoints_sq_blank)
```

The reason being that the **context** is not reachable from a ViewModel.
Any way I can get this to work?

Comment: Simply you have to provide context there. there is no other option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best practice for your queestion is using hilt dependency injection and injecting a custom class to your view model constructor

you can create a class to use it in all view models like this:

```
class AppResourceProvider(private val context: Context) {
    fun getString(id: Int): String {
        return context.getString(id)
    }

    fun getDrawable(@DrawableRes id: Int): Drawable{
        return ContextCompat.getDrawable(context, id)
    }
}
```

Then you need to inject this class to your appModule:

```
@Module
@InstallIn(SingletonComponent::class)
class AppModule {

    @Provides
    @Singleton
    fun provideAppResourceProvider(@ApplicationContext context: Context): AppResourceProvider{
        return AppResourceProvider(context)
    }
 }
```

finally you can use it in your all viewModels like this:

```
class SampleViewModel @Inject constructor(
    private val resourceProvider: AppResourceProvider
){
    fun whereYouNeed(){
        marker.icon = resourceProvider.getDrawable(R.drawable.waypoints_sq_blank)
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm almost there, the problem is that my fragment1ViewModel already has a constructor (it is taking arguments from the previous fragment). How do I inject the constructor you've shown into my fragment's viewmodel?